# Why is the indicator function of $\mathbb{Z}$ Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Title, how do I show that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty 1_\mathbb{Z}(x) dx = 0$? I know that showing this property for indicator functions of finite sets $S$ involves choosing a partition such that each interval only contains one value of the set $S$. How might I approach this problem?

Comment: Each interval contains *at most* one value of the set $S$. Many will contain none.

Comment: Technically speaking, $1_{\mathbb Z}$ is not Riemann integrable because the domain is not a closed and bounded interval. You are dealing with a function that I suspect you are to show its [improper Riemann integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral) exists.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro how might I go about showing that

Comment: Show that for each positive real number $r$ we have $\int_{-r}^0 1_{\mathbb{Z}}(x)dx=\int_0^r 1_{\mathbb{Z}}(x)dx=0.$ From this it is immediate that $\lim\limits_{a \rightarrow -\infty}\int_a^0 1_\mathbb{Z}(x)dx=\lim\limits_{b \rightarrow \infty}\int_0^b 1_\mathbb{Z}(x)dx=0,$ and hence the improper integral$\int_{-\infty}^\infty 1_\mathbb{Z}(x)dx$ exists and equals $0$ (look up the definition of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx$ in most any elementary calculus or real analysis text).